# Actionscript 3 simple image slider

Tags: actionscript, slider, scroller

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm a Noob at actionscript 3, and what I'm trying to do is make a image slider. Basically, there would be a movieClip, acting as a container, and a left and right button. when I click left button, the Container slides left and vise versa.

Now I kind of got things working, the problem is when I press say the left button, the Container moves left,and keeps moving left as many times as I click the left button. But I want it to stop, or loop, at the end of the Container, and I'm not quiet sure how to do this.

I searched all over the net but didn't find anything useful, most of what I found is really complex or heavily reliant on external libraries,  and I don't want to just copy and paste code snippets that I don't understand. Can anyone please give alittle insight on how this can be accomplished in actionscript 3.

here is a copy of my code so far

Thanks
-Noob

```
//leftButton and rightButton are movieClips on the stage
leftButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveLeft);
rightButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveRight);

//NOTE: thumbContainer is a movieClip on the stage
//Make the mask;
var myMask:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
this.addChild(myMask);
myMask.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
myMask.graphics.drawRect(6,138,534,144);
myMask.graphics.endFill();
thumbContainer.mask = myMask;

//thumbContainer moves left on button press
function moveLeft(evt:Event):void
{
    thumbContainer.x -=  myMask.width;
}

//thumbContainer moves right on button press
function moveRight(evt:Event):void
{
    thumbContainer.x +=  myMask.width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now I kind of got things working, the problem is when I press say the left button, the 
>   Container moves left,and keeps moving left as many times as I click the left button. But I 
>   want it to stop, or loop, at the end of the Container, and I'm not quiet sure how to do 
>   this.

What you have mentioned here is not very clear. From what I understand, you have a container myMask which slides off your parent container thumbContainer when you repeatedly press the left (or right) button.

Assuming this is the problem, allow the myMask container to move left or right, but check each time with the screen resolution width (Maybe have a if statement or something). Hence, move left/right only when the condition is satisfied(there is space for moving left/right)

Hope that helps!

Comment: The myMask isn't a container, its just a mask hiding the contents of the container that go off the stage. thumbContainer is the the container that is moving, and that will contain content. Also, thumbContainer is a movieClip I created an placed on the stage, sorry about that!